# How to make ursina detect the shift key in python?

Tags: python, ursina

how do you make ursina detect when the left and the right shift key is pressed in python.

if not is there any good external library to do so.

Comment: `if held_keys['left_shift'] or held_keys['right_shift']`

Answer (score 1):

Here you have all the keys handled by ursina with the values associated. https://github.com/pokepetter/ursina/blob/master/ursina/input_handler.py

So for the right shift key it's :

```py
# On the lib
right_shift = 'right shift'
right_shift_up = 'right shift up'
right_shift_down = 'right shift down'
```

```py
# For your code
def input(key):
    if key == 'right shift down':
        print('pressed right shift button')
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this:

```
from ursina import * #importing everything from ursina

app = Ursina() #Creating window

def input(key): # checking for a key input
    if key == 'shift': # checking particular key
        print('pressed right shift button') # printing if shift key pressed

app.run() # launching the window
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

I will provide code for a **class** and for **input function**

For the **input function**:

```py
    def update():

        if held_keys['shift']:
            player.speed=10
            print("Shift is Hold")
            

    def input(key):

        if key == 'shift':
            print("Shift Pressed")
                     
                
                
        if key == 'w' or key == 'a' or key == 'd' or key == 's':
            player.speed=5
```

For the **class**:

```py
from ursina import *


app = Ursina()


class Class(Button):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(
            enabled = True
            visible = False
        )
        print("Class Called")

    def input(self, key):
        def key_handler():
            print("Shift Key Pressed")

        if key == 'p':
            key_handler()

        print("Input detected")

Class()


app.run()
```

## Understanding

Ursina Engine offers many possibilities for programmers. One such offering is the ability to collect user input and perform some operation.

You can perform a collection of inputs by using the `def input(key):` function.
You can use the above mentioned function inside or outside a class as shown in the examples above.

But in a class, you have to call the **Button** object and deactivate it in `super.__init__()`, so that it doesn't appear on the screen and only then use `def __input(self, key):`.

## Webgraphy

```
https://www.ursinaengine.org/cheat_sheet.html#Keys
https://www.ursinaengine.org/entity_basics.html#Input
https://www.ursinaengine.org/entity_basics.html#Update
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here's a quick way to find Ursina's exact syntax for any key pressed
> :)

```
from ursina import *

app = Ursina()

class Class(Button):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    def input(self, key):
        print ("Input detected >>",str(key))

Class()

app.run()
```

> Or this one.

```
from ursina import *
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController

app = Ursina()

printKey = ''
you = 0

class Class(Button):
    def __init__(self,position = (0,0,0)):
        super().__init__()
    def input(self, key):
        global info
        global you
        if you == 0:
            you = 1        
            Text.size = 0.1
            Text.default_resolution = 1080 * Text.size
            info = Text(text=str(key),color = color.red)
            info.x = -0.426
            info.y = 0.1
            info.z = 0.0
            info.background = True
            info.visible = True
        else:
            if you == 1:
                you = 0
                destroy(info)

        print ("Input detected >>",str(key))              

Class()

app.run()
```